Do the two orientations on an orientable manifold $M$ uniquely witness lifts of $\tau_M: M \to B\text{O($n$)}$ to $B\text{SO($n$)}$?
For an orientable $n$-manifold $M$ and its (orthonormal) frame bundle classifying map $\tau_M : M \to BO(n)$, we have a lift diagram of the following sort:

There are two orientations on $M$. Is it ever untrue that they each correspond to two different witnesses $H$ in the above diagram?
This question is motivated by the observation that an orientation on $M$ is sometimes considered an example of an "$SO(n)$-structure" on $M$, a special case of a $G$-structure on $M$, part of the data of which one takes the 2-morphism witnessing the lift of $\tau_M$ to $BG$.

An aside example: if I take the circle $S^1$, whose (oriented orthonormal) frame bundle $Fr^+(S^1) \cong S^1 \times \text{SO($1$)}$ is in the same isomorphism class as its orientation-reversed "$Fr^-(S^1)$" (which follows from $[M, B\text{SO($1$)}] \cong \ast$), is there a way to identify these two orientations on the frame bundle via e.g. different choices of $H$ in the question?

The space of orientations on the circle is too trivial.

@DavidRoberts Can you make your sentiment precise? (Are you implying there are sufficiently nontrivial spaces of orientations on other manifolds that encode different lifts/witnesses?)

I don't think I understand the terminology here. What is a "witness"? A 2-morphism? If so, then couldn't the answer to the question in the first paragraph be yes, simply because the source 1-morphism is different?

Is the question whether for any chosen $\tau_{M,\pm}$ there are different (i.e. non-homotopic) homotopies $H$ that could fill the triangle? You should note that there is a model for $Bi$ that is a 2-sheeted covering space. So one can consider what happens in that case.

Up to homotopy, there is a fibration
$$
BSO_n \to BO_n \to B\mathbb Z_2.
$$
The space of orientations of $M$ is the (homotopy) fiber of the induced map of mapping spaces
$$
\text{map}(M,BSO_n) \to \text{map}(M,BO_n) 
$$
at the basepoint defined by the tangent bundle of $M$. This homotopy fiber is empty when $M$ is unorientable, and has the homotopy type of the space of maps
$$
 \Omega \text{map}(M,B\mathbb Z_2) \simeq \text{map}(M,\pm 1) \cong \text{functions}(\pi_0(M),\mathbb Z_2)
$$
when $M$ is orientable.  A point in the homotopy fiber is the same thing as a lift $M\to BSO_n$ together with a choice of commuting homotopy, as in the diagram appearing in the OP.
The space of orientations is therefore homotopically discrete with contractible components. This resolves your question: the answer is that for a given lift, there is just one commuting homotopy up to homotopy. In fact, we've established that even more is true: for a given lift, the space of commuting homotopies for that lift is contractible.
